# How to make a .env file on replit when it doesn't allow you to

Tags: python, file, bots, token

When I try to make a .env file on replit using python, it says this

**You can create environment variables via the environment variables sidebar!(.env files are deprecated)** I'm new to coding so I don't understand much but it has been confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

since .env files are deprecated, you have to click on the lock to make secrets
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRLe8.png)

Answer (score 0):

to make a .env file in replit
for the new update in replit
click on lock icon on the side bar

on key box put a variable like token
and in value box put the words or number you want to add like aaasfafas
and save it
and it will create .env file in lock icon
and you can use token variable in your code
[image of .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AXpg.png)